# C++ Vector3d class

Tags: c++, classes, coordinate-system

As part of a physics simulation written in C++ using SFML I needed a vector3d class.

Here is my implementation:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <ostream>

template <typename T>
class vector3d {

public:
  T x{};
  T y{};
  T z{};

  T norm() { return std::hypot(x, y, z); }

  vector3d<T> unit() { return vector3d<T>(*this) / norm(); }

  T dot(const vector3d<T>& RHS) { return x * RHS.x + y * RHS.y + z * RHS.z; }

  vector3d<T> cross(const vector3d<T>& RHS) {
    return vector3d<T>{y * RHS.z - z * RHS.y, z * RHS.x - x * RHS.z, x * RHS.y - y * RHS.x};
  }

  bool operator==(const vector3d<T>& rhs) {
    return std::abs(x - rhs.x) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() &&
           std::abs(y - rhs.y) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() &&
           std::abs(z - rhs.z) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
  }

  bool operator!=(const vector3d<T>& rhs) { return !(*this == rhs); }

  // clang-format off
  vector3d<T>& operator+=(vector3d<T> RHS) { x += RHS.x; y += RHS.y; z += RHS.z; return *this; }
  vector3d<T>& operator-=(vector3d<T> RHS) { x -= RHS.x; y -= RHS.y; z -= RHS.z; return *this; }
  vector3d<T>& operator*=(vector3d<T> RHS) { x *= RHS.x; y *= RHS.y; z *= RHS.z; return *this; }
  vector3d<T>& operator/=(vector3d<T> RHS) { x /= RHS.x; y /= RHS.y; z /= RHS.z; return *this; }

  vector3d<T>& operator*=(T s) { x *= s; y *= s; z *= s; return *this; }
  vector3d<T>& operator/=(T s) { x /= s; y /= s; z /= s; return *this; }

  friend vector3d<T> operator+(const vector3d<T>& LHS, const vector3d<T>& RHS) { return vector3d<T>(LHS) += RHS; }
  friend vector3d<T> operator-(const vector3d<T>& LHS, const vector3d<T>& RHS) { return vector3d<T>(LHS) -= RHS; }
  friend vector3d<T> operator*(const vector3d<T>& LHS, const vector3d<T>& RHS) { return vector3d<T>(LHS) *= RHS; }
  friend vector3d<T> operator/(const vector3d<T>& LHS, const vector3d<T>& RHS) { return vector3d<T>(LHS) /= RHS; }

  friend vector3d<T> operator*(const vector3d<T>& v, T s) { return vector3d<T>(v) *= s; }
  friend vector3d<T> operator*(T s, const vector3d<T>& v) { return vector3d<T>(v) *= s; }
  friend vector3d<T> operator/(const vector3d<T>& v, T s) { return vector3d<T>(v) /= s; }
  // note that scalar / vector3d does not make any logical sense
  // clang-format on

  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vector3d<T> v) {
    return os << "[" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << "]";
  }
};

using vec3  = vector3d<double>;
using vec3f = vector3d<float>;
using vec3l = vector3d<long double>;
```

And its potential usage:

```
#include "vector3d.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  vec3 z;
  std::cout << "z = " << z << "\n";

  auto a = vec3{1, 2, 3};
  auto b = vec3{4, 5, 6};
  std::cout << "a = " << a << "\n";
  std::cout << "b = " << b << "\n";
  std::cout << "a + b = " << a + b << "\n";

  auto c = 2 * b;
  std::cout << "c = " << c << "\n";
  
  auto d = b * 2;
  std::cout << "d = " << d << "\n";
  
  auto e = b / 2;
  std::cout << "e = " << e << "\n";

  std::cout << "a.norm() = " << a.norm() << "\n";
  std::cout << "a.unit() = " << a.unit() << "\n";
  std::cout << "a.unit().norm() = " << a.unit().norm() << "\n";

  std::cout << "[4, 8, 10] . [9, 2, 7] = " << vec3{4, 8, 10}.dot(vec3{9, 2, 7}) << "\n";

  std::cout << "[1, 0, 0] x [0, 1, 0] = " << vec3{1, 0, 0}.cross(vec3{0, 1, 0}) << "\n";
  std::cout << "[2, 3, 4] x [5, 6, 7] = " << vec3{2, 3, 4}.cross(vec3{5, 6, 7}) << "\n";

}
```

- I tried to "do as the ints do" and make all basic operators available.
- I realise that +-*/ operators could be free functions but I preferred to write them as friends to avoid having to template every one of them. A valid style choice?
- I realise that the `dot()` and `cross()` could be free functions, but preferred the `a.cross(b)` usage syntax.
- Minor point: I chose to format the code to wider than normal as I believe it makes it more readable / makes the patterns more obvious.
- I added some type aliases for convenience.
- Is relying on aggregate initialisation (without any constructor) and the default copy constructor a good choice?

Any comments on the code and use of member / friend / free functions please?

Comment: If all members are public anyway, you can use `struct` instead of `class` and omit `public:`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a pretty good start.  It compiles cleanly with a pedantic compiler, and the test program seems clean under Valgrind.

The first few members should not be modifying the object, so declare them `const`:

```
T norm() const { return std::hypot(x, y, z); }

vector3d unit() const { return vector3d{*this} / norm(); }

T dot(const vector3d& rhs) const { return x * rhs.x + y * rhs.y + z * rhs.z; }

vector3d cross(const vector3d& rhs) const {
    return {y * rhs.z - z * rhs.y, z * rhs.x - x * rhs.z, x * rhs.y - y * rhs.x};
}
```

Note also that unqualified `vector3d` within the scope of `vector3d<T>` means `vector3d<T>`, so we get to remove some clutter here.

Do the `*` and `/` operations of two vectors have any useful mathematical meaning?  I'd just omit these:

> ```
>   vector3d& operator*=(vector3d RHS) { x *= RHS.x; y *= RHS.y; z *= RHS.z; return *this; }
>   vector3d& operator/=(vector3d RHS) { x /= RHS.x; y /= RHS.y; z /= RHS.z; return *this; }
> ```

(Later) Having been informed that these are the rarely-needed *Hadamard product* and its inverse, it may be appropriate to retain the functionality, but as an ordinary (named) member function rather than as an operator.  This will reduce the chance of accidental misuse.

Also, don't use all-caps names for locals or arguments - it's idiomatic to reserve those names for preprocessor macros.

The friend functions are probably okay for now, but lean towards non-friend non-member functions, as this won't require any change when you add implicit conversions (e.g. from `vector3d<float>` to `vector3d<double>`) in future.

We can avoid the explicit copy if we take one argument by value, which will cause an implicit copy:

```
template<typename T>
auto operator+(vector3d<T> lhs, const vector3d<T>& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }
template<typename T>
auto operator-(vector3d<T> lhs, const vector3d<T>& rhs) { return lhs -= rhs; }

template<typename T>
auto operator*(vector3d<T> v, T s) { return v *= s; }
template<typename T>
auto operator*(T s, vector3d<T> v) { return v *= s; }
template<typename T>
auto operator/(vector3d<T> v, T s) { return v /= s; }
```

The streaming operator `<<` should not be modifying its vector argument, so pass that as a const-ref.  We can micro-optimise by passing single characters rather than one-character literal strings.

Consider adding `==` and `!=`.  Since C++20, we can kill both birds with a single stone:

```
bool operator==(const vector3d<T>&) const = default;
```

Consider constraining the template so that only arithmetic types can be used as the type T.  I don't think a vector of `std::complex` makes much sense, for example.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <concepts>
#include <ostream>

template<typename T>
    requires std::floating_point<T> or std::integral<T>
class vector3d
{
public:
    T x{};
    T y{};
    T z{};

    T norm() const { return std::hypot(x, y, z); }

    vector3d unit() const { return vector3d{*this} / norm(); }

    T dot(const vector3d& rhs) const { return x * rhs.x + y * rhs.y + z * rhs.z; }

    vector3d cross(const vector3d& rhs) const {
        return {y * rhs.z - z * rhs.y, z * rhs.x - x * rhs.z, x * rhs.y - y * rhs.x};
    }

    bool operator==(const vector3d&) const = default;

    vector3d& operator+=(const vector3d& rhs) { x += rhs.x; y += rhs.y; z += rhs.z; return *this; }
    vector3d& operator-=(const vector3d& rhs) { x -= rhs.x; y -= rhs.y; z -= rhs.z; return *this; }

    vector3d& operator*=(T s) { x *= s; y *= s; z *= s; return *this; }
    vector3d& operator/=(T s) { x /= s; y /= s; z /= s; return *this; }
};

template<typename T> auto operator+(const vector3d<T>& v) { return v; }
template<typename T> auto operator-(const vector3d<T>& v) { return vector3d<T>{} - v; }

template<typename T> auto operator+(vector3d<T> lhs, const vector3d<T>& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }
template<typename T> auto operator-(vector3d<T> lhs, const vector3d<T>& rhs) { return lhs -= rhs; }

template<typename T, typename U> auto operator*(vector3d<T> v, U s) { return v *= s; }
template<typename T, typename U> auto operator*(U s, vector3d<T> v) { return v *= s; }
template<typename T, typename U> auto operator/(vector3d<T> v, U s) { return v /= s; }

template<typename T> auto& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vector3d<T>& v) {
    return os << '[' << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << ']';
}
```

Comment: That's great, Thanks Toby. I had since caught some of these (eg const ref on << myself). The * operator is a "Hadamard product", apparently, but yes, I haven't ever used that either: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices). Pass by value for the operators is a good tidy up. And I didn't know that you can omit <T> inside the class template, so that's neat.

Comment: So you agree with the lack of a constructor taking 3 Ts and just using aggregate initialisation? I added operator== while you must have been writing your answer (sorry), and I used std::numeric_limjts<T>::epsilon  (doesn't work for integer). Bad idea? 

How would I constrain template to float/int under c++17 ?

Comment: Yes, I'd be fine accepting this code with only the aggregate initialisation.  That said, if you add converting constructors, you might find that you no longer get that as default.  In C++17, the constraint is more awkward to write (you'll need `std::enable_if` somewhere).

Comment: Thanks. And what about the use of epsilon for operator== ?

Comment: I guess that comes down to what "equal" means for your application.  Be aware that adjacent floating point numbers may well be more than epsilon apart if they are greater than 1, of course - and conversely, for much smaller values, epsilon represents a huge range.  I'd stick with plain `T==T`, and let users define their own "nearly-equal" if necessary, using `-` and `norm()`.

Comment: Fair enough. I have adopted all your changes into my (offline) code. Many thanks. You happy with the `a.cross(b)`  syntax? TBH `cross()` and `dot()` and `norm()`  where the main reasons I didn't just use the sf::Vector3 class https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Vector3.php ,although I guess I could have just written some  free functions? ;-)

Comment: Yes, the choice of member functions for `dot` and `cross` seems good.

Comment: Thanks. Final question: Why does the operator* with scalar require a separate `...typename U>` when implemented as a free function, but not when done, as I had it, as a friend function? Seems the friend function in the scope of the templated class tolerates the "upgrade" from `int` to `double`, but the separate free function template does what I would expect (ie no upgrades while matching template parameters),

Comment: That's because it's now a template function, so now arguments have to exactly match, rather than undergoing promotion.  As a friend function, it seems to have the same rules as for a non-template member function of the template class.  That surprised me, too.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock: For a rarely-used operation like Hadamard product, you could provide it as a named function rather than an operator overload.  Otherwise some uses of it are going to want to comment the use-case as a reminder that `Vec3d * Vec3d` is a Hadamard product, which they wouldn't need to if it was `v1.hadamard(v2)`.  (If you still want to provide it at all).  That would also remove ambiguity with a `vec * scalar` overload, in case the right hand side was something with possible conversion to a scalar or to a Vec3d.  And just visually distinguish hadamard from scalar in the source.

Comment: @Peter and Oliver, I've updated my advice regarding the Hadamard product operator.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an up-to-date compiler, you don't need to write `operator!=`.

`std::abs(x - rhs.x) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon()`
The type `T` is a template argument.  Does it have an `epsilon`?  You should use `if constexpr (std::numeric_limits<T>::is_exact)` to conditionally use this logic.
But, does what you wrote even work?  In fact, there is an example on the [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon) that explains:

> the machine epsilon has to be scaled to the magnitude of the values used
> and multiplied by the desired precision in ULPs (units in the last place)

and you are missing that logic.

---

`friend vector3d<T> operator+(const vector3d<T>& LHS, const vector3d<T>& RHS) { return vector3d<T>(LHS) += RHS; }`
You are passing `LHS` by reference and then forcing a copy to be made with more verbage.  It would be simpler to just pass the left argument by value:
`friend vector3d<T> operator+(vector3d<T> LHS, const vector3d<T>& RHS) { return LHS += RHS; }`

But, you can further optimize it for the case where the left argument is a temporary rvalue — something that is common when you write expressions.  Consider `z=a+b+c+d;`.  If the result of `a+b` can be modified in-place and not re-copied, you save a lot.  This happens again with `(temp)+d`.

The easiest way to do that is to add a second form that takes an rvalue reference:
`friend vector3d<T> operator+(vector3d<T>&& LHS, const vector3d<T>& RHS) { return LHS += RHS; }`
Notice that the body is the same.  But I think it's more optimal to write `{LHS+=RHS; return LHS;}`  The return is implicitly taken as `return std::move{LHS};`} because it is a simple name of a local variable or parameter.

---

`friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, vector3d<T> v) {`
What's the need to pass `v` **by value** in this function?  It seems to be an unnecessary copying.

---

`std::cout << "a.norm() = " << a.norm() << "\n";`
Writing `'\n'` instead is more efficient.  A string of one character is a lot more work to process.

---

There are a lot of places where `const` is missing.

---

> I realise that +-*/ operators could be free functions but I preferred to write them as friends to avoid having to template every one of them. A valid style choice?

You did better than you realize!  This is called the "hidden friend" idiom, and it means that these operators are *only* found during ADL.  This reduces the size of the overload set for the first pass of every `+` (etc.) in the program, and reduces conflicts introduced by any implicit conversions.

> Is relying on aggregate initialisation (without any constructor) and the default copy constructor a good choice?

Yes!

Comment: Thanks for the link to scaling epsilon. And thanks for the vote to keep the operators as friends. After incorporating most of Toby Speight's suggestions, I actually reverted to moving the operators back into the class scope as friends, because a) I didn't like the messy `template <typename T>` and then also `... typename U>` for the scalars. Plus b) exactly for your stated reason. I don't need my little "local class" to pollute the global search scope for overloads to operator+ etc. !

Answer (score 2):

### Floating point equality

> ```
>   bool operator==(const vector3d<T>& rhs) {
>     return std::abs(x - rhs.x) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() &&
>            std::abs(y - rhs.y) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() &&
>            std::abs(z - rhs.z) < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon();
>   }
> ```

We've probably all heard about the dangers of floating point equality, and seen the suggestion to compare them something like that. But this is probably not really what you want, for some different reasons.

- Whether two vectors are "close", is a different question than whether each of the coordinates are "close". For example `{ 1e99, 1, 0 }` and `{ 1e99, 0, 0 }` would be considered different this way. That may be appropriate, but it may also not be. Those vectors have approximately the same length and have an angle of approximately zero degrees between them. On the other hand they are also legitimately different vectors by another measure: the difference between them is a nice vector with length 1.
- This measure of closeness considers `1.0` and `nextafter(1.0, 10)` to be different. The distance between them is (by definition) `epsilon`, and `epsilon` is not less than `epsilon`, so the test fails. Should that be how it works? Maybe! That depends on what you want to happen. It's a suspicious behaviour though: it makes this test a test for *exact equality* for numbers that are 1.0 or higher, which looks unintentional.
- This measure of closeness considered any pair of sufficiently small numbers to be equal, even they are *relatively* far apart. Again, maybe that's what you want, but it's suspicious.
- The expected amount of numerical error for a given value depends not only on that value, but also on how it was computed.

Since you are using these vectors in a specific context, there may be an appropriate implementation for `operator==` (in which case, I don't expect that the current one does what you need it to do), but there may also not be. It's entirely possible that some of your vectors need to be compared for closeness one way, and some other vectors in another way. Just to make up some random examples: 1 meter above the ground is still 1 meter above the ground when the horizontal distance from the origin is large, that doesn't suddenly become "pretty much on the ground" just because we're located in a different corner of the map. On the other hand, two directions with an angle of almost 0 between them are close, regardless of any differences between the coordinates.

It seems reasonable to me to not implement `operator==` at all, and always explicitly state how vectors are to be compared (length of their difference, angle, or something else).

Comment: These are good points. My epsilon code was an afterthought and I did not consider all this. I think a straight `operator==() = default` as Toby Speight suggest is perhaps the only reasonable implementation - if any at all.